# Exit popup in Angular / HTML

Tags: html, angular

How do I show the popup when the user is closing or leaving the page?

Show the popup when the user is moving the mouse up fast to the top trying to close and leave the page.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Comment: Also maybe (depends on what you want to achieve) you want to look at angular route guards. https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an example `SaveUserComponent`, try like this:

DeactivateGuardService :

```
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeactivateGuardService implements  CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate>{

  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

Routes:

```
{ path: 'users/Add', component: SaveUserComponent,canDeactivate: [DeactivateGuardService] },
```

SaveUserComponent:

```
 canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    if (this.userForm.dirty) {

      alert('Discard Unsaved Changes?');
    }
    return true;
 }
```

Explanation:

Adding `canDeactivate: [DeactivateGuardService]`  to routes calls `DeactivateGuardService` everytime you want to navigate to some other route or close the browser.

The service calls `component.canDeactivate()` i.e `canDeactivate()` function of the given component

Here you can write the logic of showing alert if the form is dirty or anything else.

Comment: I'am not using of alert use of popup

Comment: Use whatever suits, this is just an example of the approach to be taken

Comment: Adrita sharma  can't understand that code how to use and please explain clarity for step procedure

Comment: Please check the explanation

Comment: How will use of popup

Comment: Adrita sharma i have small doubt

Comment: let me know your doubt

Comment: When user have moving mouse in top menu bar and tool bar visible on the popup only, this is my requirement Adrita sharma

Comment: You can add `(mouseover)='canDeactivate()'` in the menubar

Comment: where can be used this (mouseover)='canDeactivate()'

Comment: In the `menubar ` html

Comment: can't understanding previous point where menubar html, i'm working on angular project

Comment: Your Angular project have html right? Add it in that. Or clarify your qiestion show your menubar etc

Comment: Adrita sharma i have to try for you have given the code but not working

Comment: please give me another solution for popup Adrita sharma

Comment: Hii Adrita Sharma

Comment: I want when you user has leave the page show the popup, please help this

Answer (score 0):

```
// @HostListener allows us to also guard against browser refresh, close, etc.
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
canDeactivate():  boolean {
    // insert logic to check if there are pending changes here;
    // returning true will navigate without confirmation
    // returning false will show a confirm dialog before navigating away
    return condition;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.