# How to subscribe asynchronously to matdialog service for candeactivate guard?

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable, subscribe, candeactivate

I have implemented candeactivate guard using angular forms validation.
If user clicks on an ngForm Field. and tries to navigate to different Tab, user will get a custom confirmation Popup, which will say "Discard Changes ? " and returns true or false.

This is my form guard

```
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { ComponentCanDeactivate } from './component-can-deactivate';

export abstract class FormCanDeactivate extends ComponentCanDeactivate {

abstract get form(): NgForm;

canDeactivate(): boolean {
    return this.form.submitted || !this.form.dirty;
}
}
```

Component Guard

```
import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";

export abstract class ComponentCanDeactivate {

abstract canDeactivate(): boolean;

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
unloadNotification($event: any) {
    if (!this.canDeactivate()) {
        $event.returnValue = true;
    }
}
}
```

Now here is my code for confirmation popup. My problem here is if I use default confirm() method (commented line in below code), it gives windows popup,and asks for YES or NO, which works perfect. But if I use Custom Material Popup here, 
I have to subscribe to afterclosed() method, which performs asynchronously, whereas I have to wait till this method executes before proceeding. How can I achieve this ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { MatMenuTrigger, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ComponentCanDeactivate } from './component-can-deactivate';
import { ConfirmationComponent } from 'src/app/core/modals/confirmation/confirmation.component';


@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {

    constructor(private modalService: MatDialog) {

    }

canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean {

    if (!component.canDeactivate()) {
        // return confirm('You have unsaved changes! If you leave, your changes will be lost');

        const dialogRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationComponent, {});
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(res => {
            if (res == 'OK') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And from the modal I am returning 'OK' like below

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmationComponent>) { }

btnOk() {
   this.dialogRef.close('OK');
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Edit :

I have extended formdeactivate in my component

```
export class EditFormComponent extends FormCanDeactivate implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('form', { static: true }) form: NgForm;

constructor(){super();}
}
```

Stackblitz Link :https://angular-custom-popup-candeactivate.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz. You're returning a boolean where you should be returning some kind of promise or observable.

Comment: Hi kurt, I have referred this example here, but instead of confirm() method, I want to use a custom popup , which returns yes or no.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-form-candeactivate

Comment: Are you using Angular 5?

Comment: Angular 8 actually.

Comment: Can you provide an Angular 8 stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-popup-candeactivate?file=src/app/can-deactivate/can-deactivate.guard.ts

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745515/exit-popup-in-angular-html and https://medium.com/wizdm-genesys/angular-handling-unsaved-changes-with-a-pop-up-dialog-8127b9f2d79

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Your problem

You want a reusable way to prompt users before navigating away from a component containing a dirty form.

Requirements:

- There is no prompt if the form is clean
- If the user wants to exit, navigation will continue
- If the user doesn't want exit, navigation will be cancelled

### Your existing solution

Once I took a little time to understand your solution, I can see it is an elegant way of handling multiple components.

Your design is approximately this:

```js
export abstract class ComponentCanDeactive {
  abstract canDeactivate(): boolean;
}

export abstract class FormCanDeactivate extends ComponentCanDeactivate {
  abstract get form(): NgForm;

  canDeactivate(): boolean {
    return this.form.submitted || !this.form.dirty;
  }
}
```

If you want to apply this to a component, you just extend the `FormCanDeactivate` class.

You implement it using the Angular `CanDeactivate` route guard.

```js
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean {
    return component.canDeactivate();
  }
}
```

You add this to the relevant routes in your routing. I assume that you understand how all of this works, since you provided the code and demo for it.

If you simply want to prevent route deactivation when a component has a dirty form, you have already solved the problem.

### Using a dialog

You now want to give the user a choice before they navigate away from a dirty form. You implemented this with a synchronous javascript `confirm`, but you want to use the Angular Material dialog, which is asynchronous.

### The solution

Firstly, since you are going to use this asynchronously, you need to return an asynchronous type from your guard. You can return either a `Promise` or `Observable`. The Angular Material dialog returns an `Observable`, so I'll use that.

It's now simply a case of setting up the dialog and returning the observable close function.

deactivate-guard.ts

```js
constructor(private modalService: MatDialog) {}

canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate):  Observable<boolean> {
  // component doesn't require a dialog - return observable true
  if (component.canDeactivate()) {
    return of(true);
  }

  // set up the dialog
  const dialogRef = this.modalService.open(YesNoComponent, {
    width: '600px',
    height: '250px', 
  });

  // return the observable from the dialog  
  return dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
    // map the dialog result to a true/false indicating whether
    // the route can deactivate
    map(result => result === true)
  );    
}
```

Where `YesNoComponent` is a custom dialog component you have created as a wrapper around the dialog.

```js
export class YesNoComponent {

  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YesNoComponent>  ) { }

  Ok(){
    this.dialogRef.close(true);
  }

  No(){
    this.dialogRef.close(false);
  }
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-popup-candeactivate-mp1ndw

Comment: Just found that the another cause of the problem was angular ngx ui  loader, which was loading infinitely, when I dirty a form field and route to different page, and not allowing me to enter Yes /no button.

Comment: Ah. It's never simple!

Comment: any idea where we can put our YesNo popup code on browser refresh or window close. We have window:beforeunload code to capture the window reload event in ComponentCanDeactivate class in above example.

Comment: That's a whole separate question! I think this answer is already complex enough without getting involved in the `window:beforeunload` behaviour. I would do some research and then post a new question if you are struggling.

Comment: Awesome answer. you have saved my day, thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was missing the map part